# How do I get the asmx web service file in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx

I need to deploy a asmx web service to a server. I can run the service locally and it runs fine but where is the asmx file kept? In my project folder I can only see the solution file. This is my first time dealing with web services so forgive me if this is a stupid question. The service is written in C# if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your project, select `Build Menu -> Publish`. There are many publish method, but for simple way, you can choose `File System`. Define Your `Target Location` and click `Publish`. When it's Done, go to your `Target Location` using Windows Explorer and you will get all file that need to move to your IIS server virtual directory.